# Status update field blank using @"message" in the latest Facebook API

Tags: iphone, ios4, facebook

I am building a demo app where I can upload random jokes generated via the app.
My code was working fine before 12th August 2011, updated facebook api.
Now Facebook has a policy that you cannot automate the status updates via apps, the user should write the status update ? How do I get a work around for this ?

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  kAppId, @"app_id",

  MainTextView.text,  @"message",
  nil];

[_facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

This is what I used and use to work perfect . I have also tried stream.publish .

Regards

Comment: As a note - this is lon longer possible by using the included Facebook dialogs (it was disabled July 12th) - http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ .   Any solution will probably involve dealing with the API directly (and not through the included dialogs).

Comment: @dtuckernet: the OP asked for a workaround, which can be done using the Graph API with the publish_stream permission enabled. This is exactly the solution you refer to by "Any solution will probably involve dealing with the API directly"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have `publish_stream` to create a post on a user's wall. If you're trying to create a post when the user is not directly logged in to your app, you also need the `offline_access` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/).

This [blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/540/) details changes made on August 12th. I don't see anything that would have broken your app's ability to post status messages. It's more likely you are really dealing with a permissions issue.

The "policy that you cannot automate the status updates" is more of a guideline. In the documentation for the `publish_stream` [permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) this is what they say (emphasis added):

> Please note that Facebook **recommends** a user-initiated sharing model.

Meaning they recommend *against* posting automated messages to a user's wall. But they have no way of detecting whether a user initiated the post in your app or not, so they leave it up to you to be a responsible citizen.

Comment: This was disabled on July 12th.  See comments above.

Comment: I was talking about using the Graph API directly. I haven't used built-in dialogs, so I don't know about that.

Answer (score 2):

It's really simple:

POST to https://graph.facebook.com/user-id/feed the key-value pair "message":"A rabbit walks into a bar..." Your application must have the publish_stream permission.

Comment: Facebook Connect no longer allows you to pre-populate the message field. This went into effect July 12th.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: If you're using the Graph API with the publish_stream permission then it is allowed. You should reverse your downvote.